# How to add elevation from bottom only in React Native?

Tags: react-native, shadow, elevation

I have added the following style. This gives shadow from all the sides. I just want to add a shadow to the bottom.

```js
    {
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      shadowRadius: 3.84,
      shadowOpacity: 0.25,
      elevation: 5
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on IOS or the web, but Android isn't supporting it, on Android you could just define elevation and other options of shadow don't work.

If you really need to do that, use BorderBottom,

```js
 {
  ...platform.select({
      android:{
         borderBottomWidth:2,
         borderBottomColor:'#00000033'      
      },
      default:{
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowRadius: 3.84,
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Yes, I need to use borderBottom.